# Why would a list() method be used on a python list in a recursion problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm currently learning Depth-First Search in Python and a problem asked that, given a Binary Search Tree and a number N, find all paths from root-to-leaf such that the sum of all the node values of each path equals N.

I did everything right, but my code didn't work (it resulted in an empty 2D array). When looking at the solution, the only difference was "allPath.append(list(currPath))", while the code I wrote was simply 'allPath.append(currPath)'. When I made this change, the code worked perfectly Here's the full code:

```
def findPathSum(root, sum):
    allPath = []
    _findPathSum(root, sum, [], allPath)
    return allPath

def _findPathSum(currNode, sum, currPath, allPath):
    if currNode is None:
        return
    
    currPath.append(currNode.val)

    if currNode.val == sum and currNode.left is None and currNode.right is None:
        print(currPath)
        allPath.append(list(currPath))

    else:
        _findPathSum(currNode.left, sum-currNode.val, currPath, allPath)
        _findPathSum(currNode.right, sum-currNode.val, currPath, allPath)
    
    del currPath[-1]
```

What I'm confused about is that currPath is already a list, and only contains integers (which are the node values). When I print currPath before it is appended to allPaths, it also correctly displays a list with integer values. Yet after I append it to allPaths, allPaths is just an empty array. However, using the list() method on it, for some reason, displays the correct 2D array with the right integer values. I have no clue why this would work.

From my understanding, the list() method simply takes an iterable and turns it into a list...however currPath was already a list. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: `list()` also makes a shallow copy of the list, which is important if you don't want changes to to one list to effect all the lists you appended previously.

Comment: Although, for a recursive problem like this the approach can just avoid shared object/list mutations.. I find recursion (as much code) is often easier to reason about without unnecessary side-effects.

Comment: Note, `list` is a class not a method

Answer (score 2):

`list` creates a brand new list (although the elements are not brand new), a new list object. In your case, without using `list` you will simply be appending the **exact same** list object to `allPath` on each recursive call.

Therefore, since all the elements of `allPath` are the exact same list, changing that list changes all of the elements of `allPath`. For example, when at the end of `_findPathSum` you do `del currPath[-1]`, you are effectively deleting the final element of every element of `allPath`. Since in the end `currPath` will be empty, that is what you see at the end in `allPath` - a list containing empty lists.